# How to change the data before .create is called in django rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this following model

```
class User(models.Model):
    UserName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    RoleName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    ApartmentName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    UserId = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
```

I have saved the data by calling this view

```
class Register(generics.CreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return models.User.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But before the row to be created in the database table i need to change the password to the hashed form, i cant alter the post variables in the request since it is immutable.How to hash the password with make_password before saving the data?

Comment: you can try override `create` by define `def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):`. And you can try change pass before calling `self.perform_create(serializer)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `User` objects are created only from `Register` view, override the `create` method of `UserSerializer` works fine. However, users created through others ways (admin interface, django form, management command, etc.) will not have their passwords encrypted unless you provide some code to do so in all of theese ways.

To hash the password before save any user, a better aproach is create a [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#pre-save) signal or override the `save` method of `User` to hash the password (serializer and view will not change)

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.password = make_password(self.password)
        return super(User, self).save(**kwargs)
```

Make sure the password does not exist or has been changed before call `make_password` to not encode an already encoded password

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in serializer class

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields = ('Username', 'Password', #others)

   def create(self, validated_data):
       user = User()
       user.Username = validated_data['Username']
       user.Password = make_password(validated_data['Password'])
       # other
```

'make_password' could be any function that you want

Then in view just save the serializer